# Vertically align BoxView in Grid cell

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

With the following layout and styles, the BoxView isn't vertically centered such that it's aligned with the label. How do I achieve this?

```
<Grid Grid.Column="1">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <BoxView Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="Red"></BoxView>
    <Label Grid.Column="1" x:Name="lbl1"/>
</Grid>

<Style TargetType="BoxView">
    <Setter Property="WidthRequest" Value="10" />
    <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="10" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="Center" />
</Style>
<Style TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
    <Setter Property="YAlign" Value="Center" />
</Style>
```

[image]

Setting `VerticalOptions` to `Start` or `End` has the box flush against the top or bottom respectively. So, it doesn't seem to be doing central alignment correctly.

Comment: Adding this code  `<Grid.RowDefinitions><RowDefinition Height="30" /></Grid.RowDefinitions> ` to `Grid` .Testing whether it can work.And you can checking whether `YAlign` have a effect.Suggest using `VerticalOptions="Center"` to replace it having a try.^.^

Comment: Why you didn't add VerticalOptions="Center" to both items?

Comment: @NickKovalsky I probably did at some point but YAlign has the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

Use `CenterAndExpand` instead

```
<Style TargetType="BoxView">
    <Setter Property="WidthRequest" Value="10" />
    <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="10" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="CenterAndExpand" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="Center" />
</Style>
```

Update: [Here's](https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-layoutoption-differences/) a very good explanation of the difference.

Hope this helps.-

Comment: Adding that didn't have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

1) Try to add an explicit RowDefinition and its height;

2) Try adjust the label's FontSize to the BoxView size;

Or a **dirty hack**: you can add a top margin to the BoxView.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this on the Label too:

```
<Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="Center" />
```

Your code is just aligning the text position inside the label, not the position of the label itself.

Comment: I want the label to be left aligned, which is the default. The problem here is vertical alignment, not horizontal.

Comment: Ok I was obviously too quick, the message should be that you need VerticalOptions...

Comment: It says 'vertically align' in the actual question!

Answer (score 0):

When fighting text not aligning vertically:

1. Try the following: set for label

`VerticalOptions="Fill"`

```
VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
```

2. Consider a case when your elements are vertically aligned but do not seem so because of font creator settings, font adding more space to bottom or top breaking alignment. This can be solved a custom renderers system or by a silly

   `TranslationY="1"`

or `"-0.5"` whatever..